# How does FB messenger removes push notification from iOS app when I see the message on FB Desktop?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, facebook, apple-push-notifications

Whenever I get a notification about a message on my iPhone from Facebook and I reply to that message from Facebook website, that push notification goes away from my iPhone home screen. How is Facebook doing that? I know push notification don't have delivery confirmation mechanism in iOS. Here in this scenario Facebook knows I have read the message so are they pushing something to their app to remove notification? Even if they're sending a message to their app that I have read this message how is app removing that notification when I don't have background app refresh enabled for FB messenger or FB iOS app.

Comment: My guess that the notification are actually local notification which you as a developer can remove. They use the background fetch push notification to fetch the data in their app and then display a local notification when done.

Comment: But I don't have background app refresh enabled for any of those apps.

Comment: Well it was only a guess.

Comment: Yup. This thing is bugging me since forever and I am not familiar to iOS development at this level so I thought I will open the dias for others to speak :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do is after you've sent the notification you want to remove, you send a notification with the message="" and badge=0. I just tested this in a node js application and it removed the previous notification like you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

After testing myself as following, the answer by SnoApps is correct. The tests I described below assumes the account on iPhone is A.

Test 1:
    - Send message 1 from B to A => notification shown on iPhone
    - A reads message 1 on desktop => notification on iPhone is gone

Test 2:
    - Send message 1 from B to A => notification shown on iPhone
    - Send message 2 from C to A => another notification shown
    - A reads message 1 on desktop => both notifications still exist
    - A reads message 2 on desktop => both notifications gone

And I tested WhatsApp and WeChat, all of them using similar way to do this, which is when server count of unread messages becomes 0, send a silent notification with an empty body and badge 0 to iPhone. the iOS will clear the banners for you.